# Intellij IDEA 13.0 и XML

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 13.0  при создании xml файла не прописывает расширение `.xml`, в итоге создается файл типа `file`. Это как-то можно исправить или настроить?

Comment: настроить: писать ручками `.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А как Вы создаете `xml` файл? Если через меню `new` -> `file`, то никак. Только ручками. У Intellij IDEA, насколько я знаю, ничего не знает про `xml` файл

Comment: IntelliJ как раз знает и про xml, и про еще кучу форматов. Просто при создании файла указывается его тип из выпадающего списка, либо ручками вводить расширение

Comment: Он знает как их редакатировать, и знает как отобразить. Но на этапе создания он не знает, что это xml или txt

Comment: Однако не думал, что при создании нужно будет ручками писать! Позвольте поморочить еще Вам головы :) А что это за такой файл "jsp Tag Library Descriptor" (New -> XML Configuration file -> jsp Tag Library Descriptor) ? это же не одно и тоже что и XML верно?
P.S: Не пинайте сильно, я только вникаю в эту тему :)